# Redirection doesn't show up as an argument to a sourced script

Tags: shell, shell-script, io-redirection, arguments

My problem is that I can't print to the screen when I write a bash script

```
. myBashScript.sh < text.txt
```

In `myBashScript.sh` I just print out

```
echo $2
```

But instead of printing "text.txt", it show a 'newLine'. As I have been know that '<' is a new line.

Why is `$2` not `text.txt`?

Comment: Was it `./myBashScript.sh`, is that a typo ?

Comment: no it's not a typo. Because a shell script run on subprocess so the main process is waiting for it until it done. However, subprocess run it but the results will not update. So I have been used an alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're actually typing

```
./myBashScript.sh < text.txt
```

with a forward slash.

When you run `./myBashScript.sh < text.txt`, your interactive shell actually captures the `< text.txt` and interprets it as a special instruction – in particular, it interprets your command line to mean that it should run myBashScript.sh with standard input connected to text.txt.  Your shell then removes `< text.txt` from the command line before passing off control to myBashScript.sh.  So as far as your shell script is concerned, it receives zero arguments, and `$2` is empty.  Your script translates simply to

```
echo
```

which prints a newline.

If you want to actually print the name of the file, you should consider

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
```

which you can then run:

```
$ ./myShellScript text.txt
text.txt
```

If, on the other hand, you want to print the contents of the file, you should use cat(1); your shell script should be

```
#!/bin/sh
cat $1
```

which you can then run:

```
$ ./myShellScript text.txt
Hello from text.txt, a file containing a bunch of test strings.
```

Comment: thank you very much. Now i get better to understand shell script behind the scence

Comment: Just following up the question, how can I read the content of file because cat display the content of this ?

Comment: @minhcat_vo: Traditionally, Unix shell scripts don't read from or write to files; instead, they read from standard input and write to standard output, and the user relies on I/O redirection (`<` and `>`) to specify files to read and write.  However, you can pretty easily read a file using command substitution: `file_contents = "\`cat /some/file\`"` will read the contents of /some/file into file_contents.